# Sql delete sentence

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hi  I have created two tables in a database. one is omconst another one is omstarline using the following sql:

```
CREATE TABLE "omconst" ([id] INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,

[hr] INTEGER,

[name] TEXT,

[vmag] REAL,

PRIMARY KEY(id)

)

CREATE TABLE [omstarline] ([id] INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,

[begin] INTEGER,

[end] INTEGER,

[name] TEXT,

PRIMARY KEY(id)

)
```

actually, I want to delete the record of table `omconst`

```
if omconst.hr != omstarline.begin
```

or

```
omconst.hr != omstarline.end.
```

How to use the SQL Query to do this? thanks in advance...

Comment: You mean "teach me basic sql" without you even trying something? WHat about you change that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue a `delete` statement using the `not exists` operator:

```
DELETE FROM omconst
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   omstarline
                   WHERE  omconst.he IN (begin ,end)
```

Comment: thanks very much for your kind help! I want to ask you another question. After I deleted the wanted record. But the id of table omconst is not in order, just have the id of left record in table(like 1, 3, 6, 10). I want to the id of table omconst is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.......。how to deal with this issue?